# How to reverse a string in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, reversing

```
p_phrase = "was it a car or a cat I saw"

p = p_phrase.split()

p.reverse()

print(p_phrase)

r_phrase = ""

for words in p:

    if p_phrase != r_phrase + words[:-1]+"":
    
    print(r_phrase)
```

I wrote the following code to reverse the string p_phrase but the output is "was it a car or a cat I saw". I don't understand how this output is given. The output I want to achieve is "was I tac a ro rac a ti saw". Can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: `p.reverse()` reverses a list, not a string, and returns it, not reverses in place. `words[:-1]` is correct if you add another colon, but why do you need to reverse individual words?

Comment: Because the exercise I am doing wants me to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

To reverse a string use the slice capability like:

```
p_phrase = "was it a car or a cat I saw"
print(p_phrase[::-1]
```

Yields:

```
'was I tac a ro rac a ti saw'
```